# how to take a character and save it in string

Tags: c#, string, character

```
for (int z = x + 1; z.Equals(y); z++)
{
    ch = line[z];
    Console.Write(ch);
    wo = ch.ToString();
 }

 names.Add(wo);
```

In this code I am trying to extract character from specific string and I need to collect the character in new string??

Comment: so what is the problem here?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input and output that you are expecting? I'm not sure what the purpose of the code example is and your question isn't clear.

Comment: `names.Add(wo);` shoud be in for loop otherwise it will only have last value

Comment: That looks like you are overcomplicating things. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That code is just strange.  z.Equals(y) will only be true at most once.  If is not true the first loop then the loop will just exit.  Format left.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
wo += ch.ToString();
```